# Jpa Criteria query

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have a table

> Customer(Name ,Gender,State,age,city)

I want to filter my customer table by a combination of

> (gender,state,city,age)

User can either enter any one,two,three or four filter criteria. I am stuck at writing the criteria query for this How can I do this??

```
package com.thoughtclan.segmentationofcustomers.specification;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;

import com.thoughtclan.segmentationofcustomers.model.Customer;

public class FilterCriteria implements Specification<Customer> {

    private SearchCriteria criteria;


    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }


}
```

> Can you Explain in this context??

**

> This Is my service class method

**

```
public Set<Customer> filterDetails(TargetGroupDto targetGroupDto) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: Which db did you use? Postgres, Mysql or what?

Comment: I am using MySql

Comment: Can I give you a jpql query  where you can set your value as a parameter and get your result?

Comment: Yeah sure That would be very helpful

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your filter options in some class. Than just check if they exist and add criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);


    // here you receive some DTO with filter fields

    if (filter.getState != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("state", filter.getState));
    }

    if (filter.getCity != null) {
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("city", filter.getCity));
    }

    criteria.list() // return result

    session.close() // or you can use try-with-resources
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *As your question is updated later, I already asked you in comment for a JPQL query. So this answer is related with JPQL, not criteria query.*
You can do it with [`JPQL query`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html). I assume that you generate (you can generate if from [`your IDE`](https://eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm) ) or create a database entity class named `Customer` which has the member

```
private String name;
private String gender;
private String state;
private Integer age;
private String city;
.... setters and getters
```

Now add the class reference in `persistent.xml` if not exist.

```
<class>Customer</class> //if additional package exist then give the package name e.g com.test.Customer
```

Now come in the query part.

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c from Customer c where c.gender=:gender and c.state=:state and c.city=:city and c.age=:age");
q.setParameter("gender", "MALE");//Assume gender value is Male
q.setParameter("state", "Honululu");//Assume state value is Honululu
q.setParameter("city", "abc");//Assume city value is abc
q.setParameter("age", 10);//Assume age value is 10
Object resp = q.getResultList();
```

Now `resp` object contains your data. Cast the object to `java.util.List` to get data.

You can add some logic to combine your query. Suppose you have a business object `CustomerBO` instance `cbo`.

```
if(cbo.getGender()!=null && !cbo.getGender().isEmpty()){
    q.setParameter("gender", cbo.getGender());
}
and so many condition as your wish .....
```

Comment: i want a combination of these filterdetails